# How to open 1 submenu at a time while others are closed

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been trying to open one submenu at a time but I cant seem to find my problem! Looked around but havent found anything that can help me out
and it also has to stay closed at the load of the page
----HTML ---

[image: HTML PART]

```
       window.addEventListener('load', function(){


   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("niveau1");
   var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        hideAll();

        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}

function hideAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].classList.toggle("active", false);
        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show", false);
    }
}

});
```

Comment: In future, don't post screenshots of code, copy the code into a code block so that people can actually use your code

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery, you can use JQuery's `.accordain` function. Found [here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

For example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      active: false,
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfmzcw8d)

Do note that this requires that you have `<div>` rather than `<li>`.

Comment: JQuery is a javascript library, it will still work in your code